# Display spinner for a table Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I m displaying a table inside a Angular material card and want to display loader image only for that card until the card loads the data.

Able to set the visibility of the mat spinner and there is no issues with it. Problem is displaying the spinner for the entire card with transparent background and at the centre of the card. Can someone help me with it

```
<mat-card  id ="incidentcard" style="margin: 5px;" class="mat-elevation-z15" fxFlex fxLayout="column">
  <mat-card-content [style.overflow]="'auto'" [style.height.px]="'500'"

    <div *ngIf="isloading">
      <mat-progress-spinner [color]="color"
                            [mode]="mode"
                            [value]="value">

      </mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>

    <h2>Incidents</h2>
    <uitk-dynamic-table id="incidentTable" #dt [model]="incidents" [modelObservable]="incidentObservable">

      <uitk-column-def [id]="incidents.columns[0].id">
        <ng-template #cellTemplate let-col="column" let-record="record">
          <span>{{record[col.id]}}</span>

        </ng-template>
      </uitk-column-def>
    </uitk-dynamic-table>


  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `else` in Angular 2+ and you can find the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else).

In your example you would need:

```
<div *ngIf="isloading; else cellTemplate">
```

Comment: Thanks it helped but want to display the loader as a transparent image ahead of the table and centered. can you help me with css for that

Comment: In addition, if i use the ngTemplate with if else, i m getting error in populating the table data to my table.. I m getting the below error
Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._nex

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one

```
<div *ngIf="isloading" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <mat-progress-spinner [color]="color"
                        [mode]="mode"
                        [value]="value" style="order: 0; flex: 0 1 auto;align-self: auto">
```

And this is for some reference to [flexbox](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=center&align-items=center&align-content=flex-start&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto)
hopefully helps.